# Resources for Livecharts

Tags: c#, livecharts

I am extremely stuck with the data visualization part of the application I am building for a few months now, for which I want to use Livecharts in winforms. But I just couldn't find the proper resources to study it except that nasty documentation that their official website provides which is of no use to a beginner.
Please, Help me.

Comment: What do you need help with?  What [specific problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) are you stuck on?  Otherwise, if you're asking for an alternative to the official documentation then that's [off topic for this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yup I am asking for an alternative to the official documentation like a book or any blogs etc.

Comment: Ok, but that makes this both [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) ("if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format") and [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) ("Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.").  A search engine would be best suited to finding a book or blog.

Comment: I couldn't find any alternatives on google that's why I turned onto StackOverflow for help.